# Ошибка Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка ? Php файл:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=media', 'root', '');
  foreach ($file_ary as $key_file => $value_file) {
    if (in_array($value_file['type'], $types) && $value_file['size']<=$size) {
      $value_file["name"] = "$loadfilename";
      var_dump($value_file);
      $insertQueryPhoto = "INSERT INTO `photos` (user_id,path,created_at,tags,title) VALUES('$activeuserid','$path'+'$loadfilename',NOW(),'$tags','$title')";
      $pdo -> query($insertQueryPhoto) or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));

    }
```

SQL файл:

```
CREATE TABLE photos
(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id int null,
path text null,
created_at varchar(150),
tags text null,
views int null,
title text null,
CONSTRAINT media_pk
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(id)
) ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Что ты там складываешь в запросе? Откуда взялось `$loadfilename`?

Comment: В MySQL не существует оператора сложения строковых значений.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.